Im curious how array indexing works here because this works but im confused why
public Polynomial add(Polynomial other){
  int max = Math.max(coefficients.length, other.coefficients.length);
  int[] newPoly = new int[max];
  for (int i=0; i<max; i++){
    if (i<coefficients.length){
      newPoly[i] += coefficients[i];
    }   
    if (i<other.coefficients.length){
      newPoly[i] += other.coefficients[i];
    }   
  }
  return new Polynomial(newPoly);
}

Why does this work? Should the array at index i be set now and not mutable since it's an array. So why does still add to index if both if statements allow it.

Array elements are always mutable. The only thing immutable about an array is its length.

Why do you think it should not be allowed? If the index i is within the valid range of an array, the element at that index can be mutated. If that wasn't the case, how would you change the values within the array in the first place?

We're comparing two arrays, let's call them a and b. They might be the same length. That's convenient. But not always required. Here the code is saying i might be greater than the length of a or b, make sure it isn't before attempting to add the ith element from a and then from b.

Here is my explanation of the code:
import java.util.*;
public class Stack{
    public Polynomial add(Polynomial other){
        // this finds the biiger polynomial of the two
        int max = Math.max(coefficients.length, other.coefficients.length);
        
        // this array is not going out of bounds of the bigger polynomial
        int[] newPoly = new int[max];
        
        // Go till the max
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++){
            // i should not go over the length of the smaller polynomial thefore there are 2 if statements
            if (i<coefficients.length){
                newPoly[i] += coefficients[i];
            }   
            if (i<other.coefficients.length){
                newPoly[i] += other.coefficients[i];
            }   
        }
        
        // then it makes a polynomial using the new arr
        return new Polynomial(newPoly);
    }
}

But basically i starts at 0 till the end at 0. I am not sure what you inferred by " i be set now and not mutable since it's an array." but yes you are correct arrays are immutable and this method in no way is trying to change the size of the array.
